# If I cast the Awaken spell on an animal (or tree) and then swap it out to prepare a different spell, do the effects of Awaken continue?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, duration

*Awaken* is a pretty cool spell.

As a 9th-level druid, can I cast *awaken* to get a cool animal or plant friend, and then swap out the spell for some other 5th-level spell while keeping my cool animal or plant friend? Or do the effects of *Awaken* end when you swap out the spell?

I am assuming the effects of the spell continue, which makes me wonder why (outside of the consumed material component worth 1000 gp) I wouldn't just always have an awakened companion (re-casting every month) but never really keep the *awaken* spell on my list of prepared spells.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: You don't even need to re-cast it every month unless you want it to be charmed the whole time. Just treat it nicely and maybe it'll be friendly forever.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 13):

#### *Awaken* has a duration of “instantaneous”, and the awakened state has no listed end condition.

When you finish casting the [*awaken*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/awaken) spell, it simply takes effect, having a duration of “instantaneous”. There are no end conditions for the awakened state listed in the spell description, so there are none.

You are free to prepare a different spell tomorrow; this will not interfere with a previously cast *awaken* spell, since that *awaken* spell has already taken effect.

It is worth noting that **no existing spell is affected by being prepared**. Preparation just determines whether you can cast the spell that day; it never interferes with ongoing effects, unless those effects require you to recast the spell, as in *animate dead*:

> To maintain control of the creature for another 24 hours, you must cast this spell on the creature again before the current 24-hour period ends.

If you cast *animate dead* yesterday, but did not prepare it today, you would be unable to cast it again to perpetuate the effect of yesterday’s *animate dead*.

Comment: In re your last sentence, is the example of that constraint something like *animate dead*?  (Which is to a corpse, somewhat, what *awaken* is to a tree).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Correct. The idea there is that if you do not prepare *animate dead* today, you are unable to cast it today to perpetuate the effect.

Comment: In that case, it might be helpful to cite that spell as an example of the point you are making. Up to you.

Comment: I mean, if you want to get _real_ technical, you don't necessarily need to have prepared _animate dead_ to cast it - scrolls, staves, and other magic items could let you do it without preparation.